# How do I resolve an "incorrect syntax near ','"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Im writing a query for a campaign and whenever i try to run it I get an error saying the syntax isn't correct.

```
select
    opp.*
from
(
    select 
        opp.*,
        row_number() over (partition by opp.contact_email_address order by opp.status_date desc) as row_number
    from
        opportunity_data opp
    where
        opp.email_bounced = 'false'
        and opp.email_unsubscribe = 'false'
        and opp.first_mkt_medium not in ('partner', 'inbound_outbound')
        and opp.latest_mkt_medium not in ('partner', 'inbound_outbound')
        and datediff (day, cast(latest_rfq_submitted_date as date), cast(getdate() as date)) > 30
        and opp.on_cover = 'no'
        and opp.primary_group in ('Market_trader', 'Food_stand', 'Mobile_food_van', 'Caterer')
        and opp.site = 'simplybusiness'
        and opp.opportunity_status = ('quote_recieved', 'rfq_submitted', 'policy_expired_not_renewed')
) opp
where row_number = 1
```

Comment: Remove some code, retry, remove some more code, retry etc.

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from compiling your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this:

```
select
    opp.*
from
(
    select 
        opp.*,
        row_number() over (partition by opp.contact_email_address order by opp.status_date desc) as row_number
    from
        opportunity_data opp
    where
        opp.email_bounced = 'false'
        and opp.email_unsubscribe = 'false'
        and opp.first_mkt_medium not in ('partner', 'inbound_outbound')
        and opp.latest_mkt_medium not in ('partner', 'inbound_outbound')
        and datediff (day, cast(latest_rfq_submitted_date as date), cast(getdate() as date)) > 30
        and opp.on_cover = 'no'
        and opp.primary_group in ('Market_trader', 'Food_stand', 'Mobile_food_van', 'Caterer')
        and opp.site = 'simplybusiness'
        and opp.opportunity_status in ('quote_recieved', 'rfq_submitted', 'policy_expired_not_renewed')
) opp
where row_number = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because of your last `where` line. You cant use it like this. I think you wanted to use `in` instead of `=`:

```
AND opp.opportunity_status IN ('quote_recieved', 'rfq_submitted', 'policy_expired_not_renewed')
```